# Laravel Vue search-dropdown (and other components) not rendering (for some users)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

For our web-application we are using a searchable dropdown menu.
We are using a vue component for this.
However this component does not load on my local version (xampp), nor on the deployed website.
It does however show on up on the other developers local version. (artisan serve)
We are using the exact same code and went through the same steps to no avail.

**We have the following in app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Dropdown from 'vue-simple-search-dropdown';

Vue.use(Dropdown);


Vue.component('search-dropdown', require('./components/SearchDropdown.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app'
});
```

[The structure of the Resources folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aexF9.png)

**How we call it in the Blade**

```
      <search-dropdown
       :options="{{ $subCategories1->toJson() }}"
       selected.sync="selected"
       placeholder="Material"
       tag-placeholder="Please select tag"
       ></search-dropdown>
```

**how we define scripts and paths to app.js**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap') }}"></script>


<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{mix('/js/app.js')}}"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/footer.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/master.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/webkit.css')}}" media="screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)"
      type="text/css"/>
```

**Structure of our package.json**

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
},
"dependencies": {
    "all": "0.0.0",
    "module": "^1.2.5",
    "react": "~15.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.42.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1",
    "tabler-react": "^1.30.1",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.3",
    "vue-simple-search-dropdown": "^1.0.1"
}
```

}

tried anything from similar issues, ran all kinds of npm commands, rewrote the entire thing to no avail. hopefully someone can help us out!

Comment: What errors do you receive in the console?

Comment: where is your `<div id="app"> </div>` ?

Comment: the <div id="app" is around the <search dropdown>

Comment: @GetSet Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) on app.js:1 and bootstrap:1. but in the "working" version these errors appear too

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly Xampp gave issues. When I used the localhost with php artisan serve all vue components showed up. while running localhost with xampp or in development (when I deployed my xampp version) vue refuses to work.
insight in this totally welcome!

Comment: Those resources are missing in your xampp deployment it appears. Have you checked the file system for htdocs/../app.js, etc